# Compiling latex files with Base64 images in GitHub workflow

Tags: unix, github, latex, github-actions

I am trying to compile a latex document using a GitHub workflow. Normally this is not a problem.
But I need to hide an image, because it can't be public in the git. So I securely stored a Base64 file on an external WebServer. i get the Base64 text block via a WGet command and convert it back to me as an image. I do this as follows.

```yaml
   - name: Build Sign image
        run: |
          wget ${{ secrets.BASE }} -o ./sign.b64
          sudo chmod +x ./sign.b64
          base64 -w 0 ./sign.b64 | base64 -d > ./img.png
          mv ./img.png ./image.png
```

After that I compile the latex file in the workflow. I do this as follows:

```yaml
      - name: Compile LaTeX document
        uses: xu-cheng/latex-action@v2
        with:
          args: -f
          root_file: ./Hausarbeit.tex
```

I include the image as usual. However, I do not use a float environment for this, because otherwise the image is everywhere. Unfortunately not where it should be. However, it does not work with the float environment either. Therefore I do it as follows:

```tex
Run xu-cheng/latex-action@v2
/usr/bin/docker run --name a33c1f1c7b887132c44ef9c6b6c0aca1a13a3_e646d6 --label 8a33c1 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_ARGS -e INPUT_ROOT_FILE -e INPUT_WORKING_DIRECTORY -e INPUT_COMPILER -e INPUT_EXTRA_PACKAGES -e INPUT_EXTRA_SYSTEM_PACKAGES -e INPUT_PRE_COMPILE -e INPUT_POST_COMPILE -e INPUT_LATEXMK_SHELL_ESCAPE -e INPUT_LATEXMK_USE_LUALATEX -e INPUT_LATEXMK_USE_XELATEX -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/TestPy/TestPy":"/github/workspace" 8a33c1:f1c7b887132c44ef9c6b6c0aca1a13a3  "./Hausarbeit.tex" "" "latexmk" "-f" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
Compile ./Hausarbeit.tex
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 May 2021, version: 4.74b.
Rule 'latex': File changes, etc:
Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'...
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      './Hausarbeit.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'latex'
------------
------------
Running 'latex  -recorder  "./Hausarbeit.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Hausarbeit.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18>
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./Hausarbeit.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in image.png (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...egraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{image.png}
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...egraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{image.png}
                                                  
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Hausarbeit.log.
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'latex', no output was made
Rule 'latex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'Hausarbeit.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'latex'
------------
------------
Running 'latex  -recorder  "./Hausarbeit.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: Examining 'Hausarbeit.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Hausarbeit.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18>
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./Hausarbeit.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in image.png (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...egraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{image.png}
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...egraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{image.png}
                                                  
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Hausarbeit.log.
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'latex', no output was made
Failure to make 'Hausarbeit.dvi'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
Latexmk: Examining 'Hausarbeit.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
  latex: Command for 'latex' gave return code 1
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets
      Refer to 'Hausarbeit.log' for details
```

The complete workflow looks like this:

```yaml
name: Pylint

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 0 * * 4"
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Git v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Update Ubuntu
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update -y
          sudo apt-get install -y cl-base64
          sudo apt-get install wget 
        
      - name: Build Sign image
        run: |
          wget ${{ secrets.BASE }} -o ./sign.b64
          sudo chmod +x ./sign.b64
          base64 -w 0 ./sign.b64 | base64 -d > ./img.png
          mv ./img.png ./image.png

         # cat sign.b64 | base64 --decode > img.png  

      - name: Compile LaTeX document
        uses: xu-cheng/latex-action@v2
        with:
          args: -f
          root_file: ./Hausarbeit.tex 


      - name: Set up Python 3.9
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.9

      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
      
        
      - name: Build Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Latex
          path: ./*.pdf

      - name: execute py script 
        run: |
          python upload.py ./Hausarbeit.pdf
        env:
          key: ${{ secrets.FTPPWD }}
          user: ${{ secrets.FTPUSER }}
      
      - name: Clean GitHub
        run: |
          git clean -fX
```

Unfortunately I do not know what to do and hope you can help me.

With kind regards
Zeyecx

Comment: There are package with which you can directly include base64 images, e.g. https://ctan.org/pkg/luaimageembed or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inline-images

Comment: Unfortunately, since I can't use GitHub Secrets in the Latex Document, this doesn't help me. An outsider is not allowed to get the image. Neither as PNG nor as Base64

Comment: You are compiling with latex (and not, say, padlatex). You can't include png files there.